# Run PHP on jQuery Ajax Success

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, session-variables

How do I set a PHP variable to a value after an ajax call is successful?

**head.php**

```
<script>
    j.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/php/ajax/auto_select_market.php',
        data: {
            'city': geoip_city(),
            'state': geoip_region()
        }
    });
</script>
```

**auto_select_market.php**

```
include_once '../includes/library.php';
include_once '../includes/config.php';

session_start();

$market = ...

$_SESSION['CURRENT_MARKET'] = $market ? $market : ...
```

I need to set this variable after the ajax call is successful.

```
<?php
    $user['CURRENT_MARKET'] = $_SESSION['CURRENT_MARKET'];
?>
```

However, I can't just set the variable in a global variable in *auto_select_market.php*. Using `global $user;` simply doesn't work in other files.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()`?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The AJAX call doesn't complete until the PHP script exits.

Comment: be specific , the question does not stand with a meaning.  Please be clear what you are trying to do. If you want to carry certain data to various pages the keep them as session variable else please provide with info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you want to do. Yet, here's my shot:

As you have seen, if you set a `$user` variable, the values only work during the execution of the php file (i.e. the page).

If you want the value to remain in the server so it can be retrieved between pages, you may use `$_SESSION`. I'm not totally sure if you know that you can manually set objects as values on it:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

That way, you can preserve your `$user` value (and, of course, your `$user['CURRENT_MARKET']` value) between pages.

Answer (score 0):

After successful AJAX call, you would have to send another confirmation request, or you must believe, that client received all data correctly, and as success consider main client request.

The only way, how to give some data to server, is send them as POST/GET request or parameter (with no REST extension).

Answer (score 0):

Just use another $_SESSION veriable to store the data. This session veriable can be used any php file of project.

```
i.e. $_SESSION['USER'] = $user['CURRENT_MARKET'];
```

NOTE: use session_start(); if session is not starting.

Another way: you can use above line before exit php script.